# Trigger child component function with react-navigation beforeRemove

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, parent-child

Im using React Navigation for a react native app along with Expo-Video-Player. I want to track how long a video was played upon dismiss of the screen and log that in console.

The video is a component within a Page screen passed in the Stack Navigator. I wanted to be able to track the video dismiss when the user dismisses the screen, but need a way to access the Video Component's functions to check the total time played upon dismiss

In my head this would be easiest with the beforeRemove listener, and passing an event, but upon logging I've noticed there is no data that I can pull from the Page component to access the Video components functions.

Maybe my thought process of this is wrong, and there is an easier way, but nonetheless here is my code.

```
...
<Stack.Screen
    name="Page"
    component={Page}
    options={{ headerShown: false }}
    listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
        beforeRemove: (e) => {
        // This is where in my head I would call a function from Video, but can't think of a way to access it
        // Video.state
        },
    })}
/>
...
```

Page.js

```
...
<SafeAreaView>
    ...
    <Video/>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Video.js

```
...
// This is the function I want to call
function getSeconds() {
    ...
    return secondsPlayed
}
const video = useRef(null);

return (
    <ExpoVideoPlayer
        videoProps={{
        resizeMode: Video.RESIZE_MODE_STRETCH,
        source: {
            uri: videoUrl,
            },
        }}
        inFullscreen={false}
        showControlsOnLoad={true}
        videoBackground={"#fff"}
        height={200}
        videoRef={video}
        showFullscreenButton={false}
        playIcon={() => playIcon}
        replayIcon={() => replayIcon}
        pauseIcon={() => pauseIcon}
        sliderColor={"#CE4A52"}
    />
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `beforeRemove` event inside the component, something like this:

```
const video = useRef(null);

useEffect(
  () =>
    navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
      // TODO Access video here
    }),
  [navigation]
)

return (
  ...
)
```